# Qvariant usage instead of union

Tags: c++, qt, unions, qvariant

So far in my project where I had to store different data types in one place and in the end send them through a medium bytewise, I always used a custom union:

```
union union64_t
{
    quint16 u16[4];
    qint16  i16[4];

    quint32 u32[2];
    qint32  i32[2];
    float   f32[2];

    quint64 u64;
    qint64  i64;
    double  f64;

};
```

Is there a way to use `Qvariant` instead of this union? Even If I assign a q variant with something, ie:

```
Qvariant test(1.25f);
```

How can I extract it as bytes (assuming it was a `double` or `float` type)? I would appreciate all help.

Comment: Note: Type punning is supported in C++ (it is supported in C BTW).

Comment: In all cases, sending a `quint64` *bytewise* over the network is not the best idea since the [endiannes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) might differ between hosts.

Comment: I am sending this through CAN (controller area network). All targets are little endian.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like QVariant supports what you want to do. The closest method would be toByteArray, but it only returns data if the original stored values are already a QByteArray or a QString.